# Replacing data with mysql/python

Tags: python, mysql

I wrote a python script that is inserting some data to a mysql database, but also I need to insert a column by hand.

I insert by hand the data to the database column and I can see it until I run the program, (the program replace my data with the null caption).

This is the code I am using to insert to my table (I am using replace because I'm always reading a text file, where I find the data I need):

```
valores = "REPLACE INTO ACCESS_POINTS(BSSID,PRIMERA_VEZ, ULTIMA_VEZ, MARCA, RED, CANAL, ESTADO ) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(bssid, pv, uv, fabricante, red, canal, estado)
cursor.execute(valores)
conexion.commit()
```

And this is how I insert to the "AGENCIA" column and the result when the program is running:

```
mysql> UPDATE ACCESS_POINTS SET AGENCIA='TOYOTA' WHERE BSSID='04:BD:70:E8:5D:C0';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.07 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT*FROM ACCESS_POINTS;
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------+-------------+---------+
| BSSID             | PRIMERA_VEZ         | ULTIMA_VEZ          | MARCA                       | RED           | CANAL | ESTADO      | AGENCIA |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------+-------------+---------+

| 04:BD:70:E8:5D:C0 | 2017-04-02 11:54:28 | 2017-04-02 11:56:09 | HUAWEI TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD | MXConectado-E |  11   | desconocido | NULL    |

| D4:40:F0:BA:1B:44 | 2017-04-02 11:54:28 | 2017-04-02 11:56:28 | HUAWEI TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD | CASITA        |  11   | conocido    | NULL    |
+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------------+---------------+-------+-------------+---------+
```

So you can see that I inserted a data to the table, but I couldnt see the changes. Is there a way to do what I want to?

Comment: Did you actually execute the query `valores`? If so, did you commit the changes?

Comment: Yes, I did. Here is the full code:

valores = "REPLACE INTO ACCESS_POINTS(BSSID,PRIMERA_VEZ, ULTIMA_VEZ, MARCA, RED, CANAL, ESTADO ) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s')" %(bssid,pv,uv,fabricante,red,canal,estado)

cursor.execute(valores)

conexion.commit()

Comment: Please update your question to show all relevant code. Also, what is the value returned by `execute`?

Comment: I thought that I was able to do what I want to because I never tell the program to insert a data into the 'AGENCIA' column, but looks like its replacing anyway.